# How to query for something that doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query a sample database to look for sites without a domain.

We know which site a domain is associated with by domains.site = sites.id. There is no similar variable from site to domain.

So, I tried this (and a couple other joins / where filtering). Either, it's outputting about 50x the number of actual number of entries for either table, or it's outputting nothing. (This one's the former)

```
SELECT sites.name, domains.domain FROM sites 
INNER JOIN domains
ON sites.id != domains.site
WHERE sites.is_deleted = 0 AND sites.id != domains.site
```

And this one's an example the latter, which outputs nothing

```
SELECT sites.name, domains.domain FROM sites 
LEFT JOIN domains
ON sites.id != domains.site
WHERE sites.is_deleted = 0 AND site = NULL
```

I'm clearly missing something, to be able to go through the combinations, where only the site name and NULL are outputted (due to there being no domains associated with the site).

Of course, it could be a trick question, and there are simply no sites without domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your kind of query you need to start with the query that *should* work if the data existed, using a LEFT JOIN, then add the condition that the data *don't* exist. So:

```
SELECT sites.name, domains.domain FROM sites 
    LEFT JOIN domains
    ON sites.id = domains.site  /* <--- this is where you got it wrong */
WHERE sites.is_deleted = 0
    AND domains.site IS NULL;
```

Comment: Checking if something is null uses its own IS, and not =. Neat. (Well, at least it returns the reasonable number of entries of 10, which sounds convenient enough to be the answer). Much thanks.